# Spring Boot Security & Vaadin page navigation&rendering issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I have a simple Spring Boot application with Vaadin for UI and Spring Boot Security.

What I'm trying to achive is simple navigation between components from login page to main view.

this is my security configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Not using Spring CSRF here to be able to use plain HTML for the login page
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll().loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
                .failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)
                .successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
    }
```

this is my LoginView:

```
@Route("login")
@UIScope
@SpringComponent
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout {

/**
 * AuthenticationManager is already exposed in WebSecurityConfig
 */
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authManager;

private LoginOverlay loginOverlay;

public LoginView() {
    loginOverlay = new LoginOverlay();
    loginOverlay.addLoginListener(this::authenticate);
    loginOverlay.setOpened(true);

    LoginI18n i18n = LoginI18n.createDefault();
    i18n.setAdditionalInformation("Welcome");
    loginOverlay.setI18n(i18n);

    add(loginOverlay);
}

private void authenticate(AbstractLogin.LoginEvent e) {
    try {
        Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(e.getUsername(), e.getPassword()));

        SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        sc.setAuthentication(auth);

        if (auth.isAuthenticated())
            getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.navigate(MainView.class));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        loginOverlay.setError(true);
    }
}}
```

and the MainView:

```
@Route("main")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout implements AfterNavigationObserver {

    private final CertView certView;
    private final UserView userView;

    public MainView(CertView certView, UserView userView) {
        this.certView = certView;
        this.userView = userView;

    }

    private void createMain() {
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Certificates");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Users");

        Tabs tabs = new Tabs(tab1, tab2);

        certView.setVisible(true);
        userView.setVisible(false);

        Map<Tab, Component> tabsToPages = new HashMap<>();
        tabsToPages.put(tab1, certView);
        tabsToPages.put(tab2, userView);

        Div pages = new Div(certView, userView);
        pages.setSizeFull();

        Set<Component> pagesShown = Stream.of(certView)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        tabs.addSelectedChangeListener(event -> {
            pagesShown.forEach(page -> page.setVisible(false));
            pagesShown.clear();
            Component selectedPage = tabsToPages.get(tabs.getSelectedTab());
            selectedPage.setVisible(true);
            pagesShown.add(selectedPage);
        });

        add(tabs, pages);
    }


    @Override
    public void afterNavigation(AfterNavigationEvent afterNavigationEvent) {
        createMain();
    }
}
```

`CertView` and `UserView` are `@UIScope`d `@SpringComponent`s that have some DAO injected and are getting data and setting it's components right in theire cosntructor.

Now what happens when `authenticate` and `authManager.authenticate` of Login view gets called is view is being routed to the MainView which I can tell by seeing constructor being called, url changes but nothing get's rendered. Strange is that ***when I set the breakpoint in MainView's constructor page renders successfully.***

I'm quite new to Vaadin and I don't know what should the correct navigation look like so you can comment better way of doing this, but actually I would like to stay as simple as possible.

So how do I navigate correctly or get mainView's content rendered at the correct lifecycle event?

Vaadin: 13.0.1

Comment: Have you tried calling `createMain();` in the constructor and leaving out the AfterNavigationObserver? I'm not exactly sure why your version wouldn't work, but you can make it simpler by not using the after navigation stuff if not necessary, it is good to use when you want to read i.e. a parameter from the url. The injection of your two spring components should still work, and using constructor injection like you do here, the injected components are already available in the constructor so there is no need to delay its usage into a @PostConstruct or an AfterNavigation event.

Comment: sure I have tried, it's the same...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it with closing the loginOverlay before navigating to another route.

```
if (auth.isAuthenticated())
{
  loginOverlay.close(); // <-- add this line!

  getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.navigate(MainView.class));
}
```